# Correctly timing out XHR Requests in React-Native on Android

Tags: xmlhttprequest, react-native, okhttp

We're facing an issue with handling unexpected behaviours when performing xmlHttpRequests on Android devices using React-Native. We've experienced behaviour where the app becomes unavailable to complete API calls, even though the device is connected to the internet perfectly well (browser can access non-cached sites just fine). The only way to resolve this issue for our users has been to completely restart the app.

To understand the issue and its severity, we wrapped all our API calls to a timer function in production and sent reports to Sentry whenever a request took longer than 30 seconds to finish. Now we've been receiving these kind of reports in the hundreds per day with the duration sometimes being in the hours or even days.

First, instead of using whatwg-fetch, we moved to using axios so that we can manually set the timeout of each request, but this ended up not helping at all.

Second, we dove deeper into understanding how React-Native actually implements timing out XHR requests on Android, and found that it uses OkHttp3 under the hood. OkHttp has a default value for connect, read and write timeouts and react-native allows developers to change the value of connect timeout [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/121141c86b75b46fe9cbd5ec36853d75cd33615b/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/network/NetworkingModule.java#L354). However, OkHttp also has a method for setting a call timeout (everything from connect to reading the response body), but this has a default value of 0 (no timeout) and React-Native doesn't allow users to change that. More on okhttp timeouts [here](https://www.baeldung.com/okhttp-timeouts)

My question is whether this can be the cause of our worries and whether it should be reported to React-Native as a bug. Lets assume the following case:

1. app makes an API call to a resource
2. okhttp is able to connect to the resource within specified timeout limit (default 10s)
3. okhttp is able to write the request body to the server within timeout limit (10s)
4. server processes request but for some reason it fails to start sending a response to the client. I guess there could be many reasons for this like server being disconnected, server crashing or server simply losing the connection to the client without the client noticing it. As there is no timeout here, okhttp will happily wait for days on end for the server to start responding to the request.

Am I missing something here or misunderstanding how timeouts work in okhttp? Is there another, perhaps better solution than implementing the ability for developers to set callTimeout on API calls performed on android? And also, isn't it a bit stupid that developers cant set their own write and read timeouts? Cant this lead to unexpected behaviour when you want to send large amounts of data in either direction on a slow connection? 10s is quite long, but perhaps not long enough for all use-cases.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Hi, did you manage to figure it out? we have the same issue that in Android the timeout is hard 10s and our server returned the answer only after 14 sec.

Comment: Hi @LironSher, there is an [open PR](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/pull/29471) in the react-native github repo that would solve this issue. Hopefully this will get merged soon as it provides the best solution to the issue.